# How to extract an element of a spreadsheet as a string, not as an array element Google App Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

(Edited the problem description)

**What I am trying to do:** Using this [Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSXVP.png)  to collect the URLs row by row and paste each image in a new slide of a Google Slide named Output Document. I am using a function addImagetoSlide that takes in the imageUrl, the slide number and the name of the document to add images to each element of the slide.

**Where I am stuck** When I try to use dataRange (the array containing my spreadsheet element, it works well outside the while loop, but inside the while loop, it does not read the element [0][2] saying that "Cannot read Property 2 of line.. I do not understand why it works outside but not inside the while loop

```
function collateImages(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var targetDocument = SlidesApp.create("Output Document"); // Target file for the collation 
    
     var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // Range of the entire database
     Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[0][2]);
     Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[1][2]);
     Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[2][2]);
     Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[3][2]);
     var i = 0; // Iterator
     while (i< dataRange.getLastRow()){
       i = i + 1; 
       Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[i][2]);
       addImageToSlide(doubtRange.getValues()[i][2],i,targetDocument);
      }
    }
// Function to get file id from url
function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }

//Add Image with URl "ImageUrl" on slide number "index on a presentation named "deck"  
function addImageToSlide(imageUrl, index,deck) {
  var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
  var imagefile = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(imageUrl));
  var imageblob = imagefile.getBlob();
  var image = slide.insertImage(imageblob);
 }
```

Comment: *"If the row element is [url], I want it to be read as "url""*. Access it from index0:``["url"][0]``

Comment: That's helpful, but my core problem still not solved. Changing the problem description.

Comment: Quote the exact error text and the exact line causing it.

Comment: Fixed. Changed the while loop to a for loop and it seems to have worked.

Comment: It's a off-by-one error in looping.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I accidentally seem to have fixed in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code you have used is that you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist. As you are incrementing the `i` value on the last loop, when calling the `dataRange.getValues()[i][2]`, this will try to retrieve the element corresponding to the incremented `i` which falls out of the range, hence the error message you are receiving.

You can:

- move the `i` increment after calling the `dataRange.getValues()[i][2]`;
- use a `for` loop;

#### Reference

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange).